Batch update of records in MongoDB
I iterated over records in the batch step and in Batch Aggregator I wanted to update all of them at once in mongoDb. Is there a way to update them all together or I need to separately update each one of them in the batch step?
For example this is my payload in batch agregator :
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e4224b"
    },
    "rocket": {
      "name": "Falcon 1"
    },
    "success": false,
    "details": "Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle",
    "name": "FalconSat",
    "date_utc": "2006-03-24T22:30:00.000Z",
    "id": "5eb87cd9ffd86e000604b32a"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e4224d"
    },
    "rocket": {
      "name": "Falcon 1"
    },
    "success": false,
    "details": "Residual stage 1 thrust led to collision between stage 1 and stage 2",
    "name": "Trailblazer",
    "date_utc": "2008-08-03T03:34:00.000Z",
    "id": "5eb87cdbffd86e000604b32c"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e42251"
    },
    "rocket": {
      "name": "Falcon 9"
    },
    "success": true,
    "details": null,
    "name": "COTS 1",
    "date_utc": "2010-12-08T15:43:00.000Z",
    "id": "5eb87cdeffd86e000604b330"
  }
] 

I wanted to update corresponding records in my db but most examples of update that i have seen in guide are for one record only.
I tried updating my XML with the answer provided but I don't entirely understand how it supposes to look like since it produces errors: Unable to resolve reference of: db. Unable to resolve reference of: documents.


                        <mongo:update-documents collectionName='#["Launches"]' doc:name="Update documents" doc:id="bf4fd676-8062-49ae-bfa5-9bddd4a1c8b8" config-ref="MongoDB_Launches_Config" >
                            <mongo:content-to-update ><![CDATA[#[db.aggregate([
  {
    "$documents": payload
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "Launches",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])]]]></mongo:content-to-update>




If these are the documents with the updated data already, then add a final $merge stage.

Yeah can you be mor specific about how you generated this list and how you know what the changes are? You can definitely do things like issue a bulk write operation that contains all of your changes, but it would be ideal to know more about your specific context

You can load your batch payload with $documents and perform a $merge to update into the collection.
db.aggregate([
  {
    "$documents": // your batch payload here
    [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e4224b"
        },
        "rocket": {
          "name": "Falcon 1"
        },
        "success": false,
        "details": "Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle",
        "name": "FalconSat",
        "date_utc": "2006-03-24T22:30:00.000Z",
        "id": "5eb87cd9ffd86e000604b32a"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e4224d"
        },
        "rocket": {
          "name": "Falcon 1"
        },
        "success": false,
        "details": "Residual stage 1 thrust led to collision between stage 1 and stage 2",
        "name": "Trailblazer",
        "date_utc": "2008-08-03T03:34:00.000Z",
        "id": "5eb87cdbffd86e000604b32c"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e42251"
        },
        "rocket": {
          "name": "Falcon 9"
        },
        "success": true,
        "details": null,
        "name": "COTS 1",
        "date_utc": "2010-12-08T15:43:00.000Z",
        "id": "5eb87cdeffd86e000604b330"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

The syntax in playground is slightly different due to some limitations in playground around $documents. The above syntax should work in your MongoDB setup.

Just a note, you cannot use $documents together with $merge in sharded cluster, you get error $documents must run on mongoS, but cannot :: caused by :: $merge must run on a shard
